# Strange spam not appearing in any gmail web interface folder (including spam folder) but appears in inbox when reading email via imap

Tags: gmail, spam-prevention, gmail-imap

I received the following spam (I included the header) when reading my email by alpine email client. Strangely this email does not appear in any gmail web interface folders (including spam folder).

My question is how is it possible?
I changed my real email username by 'mygmailaddress'.

```
Delivered-To: mygmailaddress@gmail.com
  Received: by 10.76.73.39 with SMTP id i7csp73619oav; Sat, 11 Oct 2014 06:21:24
   -0700 (PDT)
  X-Received: by 10.42.188.70 with SMTP id cz6mr22583683icb.19.1413033683878;
   Sat, 11 Oct 2014 06:21:23 -0700 (PDT)
  Return-Path: 
  Received: from mta951.e.menswearhouse.com (mta951.e.menswearhouse.com.
   [8.7.44.55]) by mx.google.com with ESMTP id
   c7si19866108ick.65.2014.10.11.06.21.23 for ; Sat,
   11 Oct 2014 06:21:23 -0700 (PDT)
  Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of
   bo-b9gytf7bfbsq26auzcb7wbyae3mm75@b.e.menswearhouse.com designates 8.7.44.55
   as permitted sender) client-ip=8.7.44.55;
  Authentication-Results: mx.google.com; spf=pass (google.com: domain of
   bo-b9gytf7bfbsq26auzcb7wbyae3mm75@b.e.menswearhouse.com designates 8.7.44.55
   as permitted sender)
   smtp.mail=bo-b9gytf7bfbsq26auzcb7wbyae3mm75@b.e.menswearhouse.com; dkim=pass
   header.i=@e.menswearhouse.com
  DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=e.menswearhouse.com;
   s=20120622; t=1413033683; x=1428758483;
   bh=OWFSSiyHtpNZkp3tGZ5MupJeTAmHfwChuuuTj42uh5I=; h=From:Reply-To;
   b=ue+Kfb3CNHPy2euZ/5ODaSXYu0AdMh9QU8ly6xc8/1u+/GzX7UaQOU/4/movIZ9SJ
   syFPjLIlmNDwoMatW4pfkKlRdZ38d9rGkQGqsHYLaTCsMTyzcsMJpzWX58fBQRXnn0
   xTg2ZYK59Yn1LxY4dEkjH5g2WRJY/yMij+Yejorw=
  DomainKey-Signature: a=rsa-sha1; q=dns; c=nofws; s=200505;
   d=e.menswearhouse.com;
   b=jdKxhnqThIj5HItJxSrHtMnLS6g5cGJh4xXZbu95tBdXdp7PaLx/W62SN4H9rUfiRtSXmjwmFc8rHxAW2jaYw036/Tui8ENAq2gpkN
      FPP1Yvs9gcEwQqOgJPTGoS+kwcLoZiDWberjrN0Qzoylx4eMsWW7MfyRgW1kAgL4+a0pI=;
   h=Date:Message-ID:List-Unsubscribe:From:To:Subject:MIME-Version:Reply-To:Content-type;
  Date: Sat, 11 Oct 2014 13:21:23 -0000
  Message-ID: 
  List-Unsubscribe: 
  From: "Men's Wearhouse" 
  To: mygmailaddress@gmail.com
  Subject: Warm up for fall.
  MIME-Version: 1.0
  Reply-To: "Men's Wearhouse"
   
  Content-type: multipart/alternative;
   boundary="=b9gytf7bfbsq26auzcb7wbyae3mm75"
  Parts/Attachments:
     1 Shown     50 lines  Text (charset: ISO-8859-1)
     2   OK    ~447 lines  Text (charset: ISO-8859-1)
  ----------------------------------------
```

Comment: Silly question but can you try searching for this email in your GMail interface? I've had a few issues in the past where emails are not seen, yet a search does detect them

Comment: @Dave I confirm that after your suggestion I found it by a search in the gmail web interface. Gmail' search claims it is in the Inbox, but when opening the inbox I cannot find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perform a  search using the GMail web interface usually finds the "missing" email (or the stray).

For some reasons, emails don't always show where you expect them (and I've had this issue in many web and software based clients). I've had issues where I can't find an email and it turns out to be in an unexpected folder, or a folder I couldn't access or it was a glitch in the program.

Typically a search in gmail finds the email, at which point you can delete it (or do what you need to).